# Instagram embed picture showing up over (Broken and Overlapping) other elements

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

And this is how it should be showing up:
[image]
As you can see, in the first screenshot the picture is appearing above the text. In the second one everything is correct. I'm embedding Instagram posts into my website and what happens is that sometimes everything is showing up ok on the page and sometimes not (After refreshing the page).

My code is pretty simple:

```
<div style="width:40%; float:left"><!-- Instagram Post Embed -->
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/p/Bflevi2lUWS/" data-instgrm-version="8" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50.0% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div><p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/Bflevi2lUWS/" style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">Uma publicação compartilhada por MIAMI TIPS (@miami_tips)</a> em <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2018-02-24T16:10:00+00:00">24 de Fev, 2018 às 8:10 PST</time></p></div></blockquote>
    <script async defer src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>

    </div>

<div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas consequat nisl a euismod volutpat. Sed ultrices nulla vel mattis pulvinar. Nunc porttitor sem sem, faucibus molestie nibh eleifend ut. In non nunc nibh. Aenean mattis euismod diam, in faucibus quam aliquet vitae. Etiam quis urna nec enim facilisis ultricies. Phasellus blandit eleifend diam eu luctus. Nam venenatis efficitur lorem, id volutpat augue auctor vel. Integer ut lectus placerat, vulputate tellus a, tristique massa. Vestibulum scelerisque massa et gravida hendrerit. In auctor elementum tincidunt.

Maecenas ultricies arcu lacinia efficitur faucibus. Mauris vestibulum, dolor ac vulputate sodales, nisi augue aliquam nisi, in ullamcorper lectus purus vel risus. Suspendisse fermentum at mauris vitae ullamcorper. Proin condimentum vel enim ut vehicula. Etiam at diam luctus, pharetra libero sed, finibus eros. Nam mollis risus purus, rhoncus posuere risus sodales iaculis. Sed vel sem magna. Aenean pretium nunc nec diam consectetur mattis. Mauris non ultricies urna.

Quisque hendrerit lorem id sem dignissim faucibus. Sed et suscipit quam. Praesent maximus rutrum nibh cursus finibus. Vestibulum non nulla at tortor sollicitudin vulputate nec quis diam. Vivamus lobortis rutrum neque et ultricies. Donec eros ex, mollis sit amet libero vel, vehicula auctor mauris. Sed suscipit justo eu ipsum vehicula condimentum. Nam vulputate sit amet quam vel congue. Maecenas gravida libero eget est aliquet ornare. Suspendisse suscipit risus a ligula convallis, in commodo erat fringilla. Aliquam mattis mi ut sapien ullamcorper hendrerit feugiat ut neque.

</div>
```

I don't know what's going on, but I believe that's because the instagram element is loading before the DOM.

The code is just as simple as that, there is nothing else to show. Does anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/7vwxdd/instagram_embed_suddenly_broken_and_overlapping/

I'm not sure if that's 100% accurate, but so far so good, haven't seen the problem anymore.

It appears to be a problem with Instagram itself. Changing the script source from `https://www.instagram.com/embed.js` to `https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js` fixes the problem, but I'm still testing it.